# Passing binary command line parameters using Delve GO Debugger

Tags: docker, go, delve

I have a **GO binary** `app` running inside a **Docker container**. I have the following command to execute the binary and pass the command line argument `-env-file=dev.env.list`.

`CMD ["/dlv", "--listen=:3500", "--headless=true", "--api-version=2", "exec", "/app", "--", "-env-file=dev.env.list"]`

I can debug **GO binary** `app` but I'm not able to get the command line argument. The documentation for [Exec](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/usage/dlv_exec.md) does not mention about command line arguments.

How can I pass command line parameters to the binary app using Delve GO Debugger?